# Why I get AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute '3f'?

Tags: python

I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute '3f'
```

I don't understand why I am getting it, I am following the example straight from the book "applied text analysis"

The chunk of code in python is:

```
total = sum(words.values())
for gender, count in words.items():
pcent = (count / total) * 100
nsents = sents[gender]
print(
"{0.3f}% {} ({} sentences)".format(pcent, gender, nsents)
)
```

I see that **pcent** clearly will return a float, why the author tries to apply .3f what  am I missing?

Comment: Weird;Try this ```:.3f```.format() Author is limiting the decimals precision.

Comment: wow, it works! Is the ':' always required for this formatting? why the author has a mistake on the very first example of the book??

Comment: It's not a mistake, thing's change with time but book's don't necessarily reflect that!

Comment: out of curiosity would this have worked in python 2?

Comment: I am not actually sure but in very early days Python had introduced % formatting (similar to C/C++ etc), after that in Py2.x they introduced string formatting (the example you have imho) and then in Py3.6+ they introduced the f-strings! Prefer fstrings always unless you are logging something where that string formatting comes more handy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead,

```
  print(
"{:.3f}% {} ({} sentences)".format(pcent, gender, nsents)
)
```

Refer the latest [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#format-examples) for more examples and check the Py version!

Comment: Well, to be honest I thought the book was the 'latest doc' so far, it was written only last year!

Comment: It will soon be 2 years old then..

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `{:.3%}` instead of `{:.3f}%`.

It will transform the value into percentages automatically.
That means `"{:.3%}".format(0.3)` will print `"30%"` while you have to write `"{:.3f}%".format(0.3 * 100)` to get `"30%"` as well.